# Exception while adding an object to a list

Tags: hibernate, list, struts2, action

I am trying to build up a list of objects of type `SomeClass`. when I try to add an element to the list using `listName.add(objectOfSomeClass)`, an exception occurs. When I try to print the message for that exception, I get `Null`. So I am unable to find the problem.

I am showing you the code in my action class. What is being done here is:

I iterate over a list of employees, and for each employee I fetch records for the salary.At the end of the loop I try to add this salary object to the list of the same type. This is where I get the exception. I tried and tried and still haven't figured out the problem. I guess there is something that I don't know and am doing wrong.

I am using hibernate to connect to database (if its important to know here).

Here is the code of the action class:

```
private SalaryQuery salaryQuery = new SalaryQuery();
private List<SalaryPersistence> salaryDetail;
public List<SalaryPersistence> getSalaryDetail() {
    return salaryDetail;
}
public void setSalaryDetail(List<SalaryPersistence> salaryDetail) {
    this.salaryDetail = salaryDetail;
}
private List<SalaryPersistence> salDet;
public List<SalaryPersistence> getSalDet() {
    return salDet;
}
public void setSalDet(List<SalaryPersistence> salDet) {
    this.salDet = salDet;
}

SalaryPersistence sal = new SalaryPersistence();

private List<EmployeePersistence> employees;
private EmployeeQuery employeeQuery = new EmployeeQuery();

public String execute(){

    employees = employeeQuery.list(""); //gets a list of employees
    Iterator<EmployeePersistence> itr = employees.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        EmployeePersistence empl = itr.next();
        salDet = salaryQuery.list("where Employee_Code='" + Integer.toString(empl.getEmployeeCode()) + "' and month = '" + dbMonth + "' and year = '" + dbYear + "'");

        if(salDet.isEmpty()){
            if(dbMonth==1){
                salDet = salaryQuery.list("where Employee_Code='" + Integer.toString(empl.getEmployeeCode()) + "' and month = '" + (dbMonth-1) + "' and year = '" + (dbYear-1) + "'");
            }else{
                salDet = salaryQuery.list("where Employee_Code='" + Integer.toString(empl.getEmployeeCode()) + "' and month = '" + (dbMonth-1) + "' and year = '" + dbYear + "'");
            }

            if(salDet.isEmpty()){
                SalaryPersistence salary = new SalaryPersistence();
                salary.setEmployeeCode(Integer.toString(empl.getEmployeeCode()));
                salDet.add(salary);
            }
        }
        //// salDet will have only one object corresponding to salary of an employee////
        Iterator<SalaryPersistence> sitr = salDet.iterator();
        sal = sitr.next();
        salaryDetail.add(sal);//I am trying to add the only object in salDet to salaryDetail, but am getting and exception with 'null' message//
    }
}
```

Please help me find the problem.

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

I just found out that I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` (tried printing the stacktrace) when I try to add. I think this should be helpful.

Comment: due to laziness, can you show at which line you are getting exception :)?

Comment: @Umesh : The last line i.e. `salaryDetail.add(sal);`. Also I found out that the exception is a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: add lines  `salaryDetail=new ArrayList<SalaryPersistence>()` before add method it should work or init your salaryDetail at any place of your choice before adding something

Comment: Wow. That worked. But why did I never require it before, I have been using lists in a similar way before also.

Comment: that means might be you `init` it some way or other else this will never work :)

Comment: Ok. I will look into this Thanks!! Why don't you post it as an answer. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not initialize your list which is causing NPE.All you need to have to initialize your `salaryDetail` list something like

```
salaryDetail=new ArrayList<SalaryPersistence>();
```

All you have to add this code before you calling any method on your list.

Comment: I just looked into my previous uses. I have been using the list as `this.listName = //a function that returns list//`. Here I did not require a separate initializing. Whats the difference here.

Comment: you function must be returning a valid list instance and all you doing is pointing that in short you are returning fully initializing list :)

Comment: okz, Right. Actually hibernate was doing the initialization on its own. So I never needed it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you declared a variable salaryDetail as List, but you are not created any memory(i.e. instantiating it).. you can do this by any of the concrete implementation class of java.util.List(ArrayList or Vector).. then you never get this exception..

NullPointerException occurs when you tring to access something which is null.
salaryDetail.add(sal) is understood by JVM as below.
null.add(sal)---> gives NullPointerException